# IP forwarding between two interfaces on Windows Server from Linux box

Tags: windows, networking, ip, iptables, windows-server

I have two VMs, one Ubuntu Server and one Windows Server 2016. On both machines I have a virtual switch with NAT (Hyper-V vSwitch on Windows) with Docker containers connected to them. On Linux my vswitch is `192.168.0.1/24` and on Windows my vswitch is `192.168.1.1/24`. I'd like to be able to reach containers across machines using a combination of static routing and IP forwarding. The external network that the VMs are connected to is `10.0.0.0/23`.

I've got it working when pinging Linux containers (on the `192.168.0.1/24` network) from the Windows VM. I achieved this by adding a static route on the Windows VM to the Linux VM (which is at `10.0.0.10` on the external network):

`New-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix "192.168.0.0/24" -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet" -NextHop 10.0.0.10`

Then on the Linux box, I enabled IP forwarding and did some iptables magic:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o cbr0 -j MASQUERADE # cbr0 is the vswitch NAT interface which the containers are connected to
iptables -A FORWARD -i cbr0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o cbr0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i cbr0 -o cbr0 -j ACCEPT
```

While this is all working, I'm struggling to achieve the same thing in the opposite direction (Linux -> Windows). I've added a static route to my Linux box like so, to point the `192.168.1.1/24` network to the Windows box (at `10.0.0.11`):

```
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 10.0.0.11
```

Then I enable IP forwarding on the Windows box:

```
Get-NetAdapter | Set-NetIPInterface -Forwarding Enabled
```

This then allows me to ping the default gateway of the vSwitch on the Windows box from the Linux box, which is `192.168.1.1`. However, trying to ping anything else on that interface doesn't work (e.g `192.168.1.100`). I imagine I need to do the equivalent of iptables on Windows, but I haven't been able to find an alternative. Does anyone have any ideas?

Cheers